# FactoryGirl How create a instance which is created by association on callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Consider two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :book

  after_create :create_book
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validate_uniqueness :user_id
end
```

Each user can have and can only have one book. Then I have two Factory defined in my specs:

```
factory :user do
end

factory book do
  user
end
```

Then here's the question, when I am writing test for `Book`, I'd like to create a record `book1`(let's call it) for `Book`, when I use `FactoryGirl.create(:book)`. It will create an instance of `Book` and then tries to create the association defined `user`. After creating the user, the `after_create` is trigger, and `book2` is created for `user`. Then it tries to bind `book1` with `user` and is blocked by the uniqueness association.

Now I am using `book = FactoryGirl.create(:user).book`. Is this the best/right way to do that? I think it's note so intuitive, as I am testing `Book`, I think it would be the best to have `book = FactoryGirl.create(:book)`

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use `trait` for this. Here is the example:

**Factory**

```
factory :user do
  # Your config here

  # Use trait
  trait :without_book do
    after(:build) do |user|
      allow(user).to receive(:create_book).and_return true
    end
  end

  trait :with_book do
    allow(user).to receive(:create_book).and_call_original
  end

  transient do
     # Use this by default but don't use this line also works
     # because we create book in the normal behavior
     with_book
  end
end
```

**Spec**

```
context 'test user without book' do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :without_book)

  it 'blah blah' do
  end
end

context 'test user with book' do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :with_book)
  # Or simply use this, because :with_book is default
  # let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user)

  it 'blah blah' do
  end
end
```

Btw, as you see, I use a stub method at `allow(user).to receive(:create_book).and_return true`, basically, this utility method comes from `rspec-mock`, and we need this config to make it available in factory:

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner.class_eval do
  include RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods
end
```

Ideally, you can handle `create` or `not create` a book by using `trait` for a user, it will be easier to simulate the scenario!

Comment: Great idea. But I got `undefined method `and_return' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Static:0x007fd0fe140c18> (NoMethodError)` trying out your samples, I don't know why. But I get around with `after(:build) { |user| user.class.skip_callback(:create, :after, :create_book_for_user ) }`

Comment: Do you include `include RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods` in rails_helper.rb

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed that at first. I am just trying that out, with `include RSpec::Mocks::ExmpleMethods` in my `rails_helper.rb`. I still get `NoMethodError: undefined method `allow' for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x007fa33a963e00>`

Comment: Hey it should be `RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods`, btw which rspec-mock version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I spell it right in my code. I am using  `rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)`

Comment: 1 more try: just add this line `require 'rails_helper'` to you spec file?

Comment: it was my fault. I was testing it with `rails c test`. I just forgot that, it was totally correct running in `rspec`. Sorry for that. Your idea works like a charm. Thanks a lot.